# Prove that a tensor that has $p+q=3$ is equal to zero

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Recently I have been studying differential geometry and I found this on my reference notes :

> A tensor of type (p,q), where p+q=3, (rankT=3) invariant with respect to any coordinate changes is identically zero

I guess that the general idea would be to obtain that $T^{i}_{j}=-T^{i}_{j}$ and then that would imply that the tensor is zero, but im not sure how to proceed and to get there. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's p and q here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. I'm taking a tensor of the type (p,q). At least the book has this notation, and then the statement appears as I put it.

Comment: Is that an exact quote? Perhaps you’ve omitted some assumptions on the tensor? As written, it is wrong.

Comment: @Deane, yes it is an exact quote, the statement is given in that ambiguous way

Comment: something must be missing.   tensors are invariant with respect to coordinate changes already.   that's kinda the point of them.

Comment: also in your example T is a (1,1) tensor but 1+1=2, not 3

Comment: Perhaps you could say which book this is from? And maybe quote the author's definitions of a tensor and a coordinate change?

Comment: @Deane, to clarify it is in the notes of my proffesor. I said book, and I apologize as english is not my native language. Maybe there is something wrong, so I'll ask and if I have to clarify things I'll edit the post

Comment: Ok. Sounds good.

Comment: The tensors of the form ${\mathbf U}\otimes{\mathbf V}\otimes{\mathbf W}$ where each factor is either a $(0,1)$ or a $(1,0)$ tensor are of rank three and obviously not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the behavior of the components of $T$ under a coordinate change, which involves the matrix of partial derivatives of the coordinate change and/or its inverse (depending on $p$ and $q$). But what you can always do is to start from a local coordinate chart $x^i$ and then consider $\tilde x^i=-x^i$ for all $i$. The derivative of this map in each point is minus the identity matrix, so its inverse is minus the identity map, too. So regardless of $p$ and $q$, the action on each component of $T$ will simply be multiplication by $(-1)^3=-1$, which indeed shows that each component of $T$ has to equal its negative and hence be zero.

Comment: Sorry. I am very confused. This shows that a component of $T$ in the $\bar{x}^i$- coordinates is minus that component in the $x^i$-coordinates. So far I can follow. Components of tensors can change under coordinate transformations but I don't see how they become zero here. What I see is $\overline{T}_{ijk}=-T_{ijk}\,.$

Comment: The only reconciliation I can think of is that OP's professor meant $\overline{T}_{ijk}=T_{ijk}$ for any coordinate change. This is however not what is meant by coordinate invariance.

Comment: The only way I can make sense out of the question is that it asks the question of absolutely invariant tensors (like the $\binom11$-tensor $\delta^i_j$), which have the same expression in any coordinate system. For these the claim in the question is true and the argument is in my answer. In the usual interpretation of coordinate invariance, the question does not make sense because in that sense these are just sections of some tensor bundle and the space of sections of any such bundle is infinite dimensional (and hence non-zero).